# Making --std=C++17 default in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, macos-catalina

I use `g++ --std=c++17 sol.cpp` very frequently so I want to make this as default. To do this I have gone through many of the answers here but none of them are working in my system.

I have tried alias,

```
alias g++='g++ --std=c++17'
```

in my `.bash_profile` but it is not working.

Please help me with this for which I will be thankful to you.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple changed shell from bash to zsh due to licensing concerns.
Therefore configuration files are now .zshrc and .zprofile.

Add alias to `~/.zshrc`

```
alias g++='g++ -std=c++17'
```

Don't forget to restart Terminal.